# Problema ao fechar aplicação com thread dentro de um componente

Tags: delphi, thread

Estou desenvolvendo um componente (indicador visual) que para busca dos dados no Banco de dados e gerar o indicador em si usa uma Thread. Essa Thread está dentro do próprio componente. Funciona tudo certo, exceto quando eu fecho a aplicação e a Thread está sendo executada.
Aí ocorre o erro "Runtime 216".

Detalhes:

- Na criação da Thread ela é setada como `FreeOnTerminate`;
- Se houver apenas um componente (indicador visual) no `form`, consigo fechar a
  aplicação sem problemas. O problema ocorre quando há mais de um componente;

Segue trecho do código:

```
constructor TWThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);  
begin  
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);  
  FreeOnTerminate := True;  
  oQryThread      := TTIQuery.Create(nil);  
  oCdsThread      := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);  
  oDBThread       := TTIDatabase.Create(nil);  
end;

procedure TTIWidget.EventoOnTerminate(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  if Assigned(oThread.oQryThread) then  
  begin  
    if oThread.oQryThread.Active then  
      oThread.oQryThread.Close;  
    FreeAndNil(oThread.oQryThread);  
    if Assigned(oThread.oCdsThread) then  
      FreeAndNil(oThread.oCdsThread);  
    if Assigned(oThread.oDBThread) then  
      FreeAndNil(oThread.oDBThread);  
  end;  
  oThread := nil;  
end;
```

Comment: Você não poderia encerrar essas threads no evento OnDestroy do Form onde estão os componentes?

Comment: Sim, porém quero fazer algo mais genérico para não ficar mexendo na aplicação onde estão os componentes.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Você pode descender todos os forms de sua aplicação de um form genérico que verifica se esses componentes especificamente estão em execução e trata de encerra-los.

Comment: Poderia postar o trecho do Create/Execute/Terminate da sua thread ?

Comment: Pergunta editada

Comment: Como você setá o `FreeOnTerminate`, oque acontece se você tirar o `oThread := nil;` ?